# Looking for a Vertigo comic book about a cop/private detective who is comatose or can't tell what's real and what isn't

Tags: story-identification, vertigo-comics

I'm looking for a comic book that was published by Vertigo in the mid-1990s to early 2000s. It's about a cop or private eye that is either comatose or is unable to tell reality and his delusions apart. If I remember correctly, the cover of the book shows the protagonist lying in a (hospital?) bed. The title MIGHT include the word "blue", but in that regard my memory is really vague. Does anyone know the comic book I'm talking about?

Comment: Any particular SciFi elements (other than a publisher who was heavy on SF/Fantasy, given that Vertigo also did crime and other genres) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warren Ellis' *Dark Blue***

Found it! Avatar Comics, not Vertigo.

Strictly speaking, it isn't fantasy, but the 'hero' imagines a blue cat or fairy or some such talking to him and guiding him (if I recall correctly).

Description:

> Violent, disturbed cop Frank Christchurch has too many problems. He has a partner who’s convinced he’s mentally ill, a commanding officer on smack, and a killer whom no-one else seems to want to catch. The pressure of his savage life is triggering murderous outbursts and hallucinations. Frank Christchurch is on the way down. And he might take everyone with him. Nothing is as it seems.

[image]

Comment: @glahn: If this is the comic you were looking for, please accept the answer as correct to close the question.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!